# How do we get from LHP to RCP on the poincare sphere?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, polarization, geometry

A paper that I was reading wanted to transform the jones matrix of linearly horizontal polarization(LHP) to right circular polarization(RCP).

The paper states:

> Consider... $J_{LHP}\to J_{RCP}$... In order to get to RCP from an initial LHP we must first rotate down to the equator to L+45. This transformation takes its path all the way around the sphere in a helical, descending manner and is physically accomplished by rotating a Waveplates in the plane of polarization.

The author doesn't provide information on how we finally reach RCP. From my understanding we reached a linear state($L+45$) through a path that traces elliptical states. How do we arrive to RCP or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the geometry proposed by the author but consider the following:

The left-handed and right handed circular light are described by the Jones vector
\begin{align}
\vert LHP\rangle&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\ i\end{array}\right)\, ,\\
\vert RHP\rangle&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\ -i\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
so a rotation about the $\hat z$ axis $R_z(\theta)=e^{-i\theta \sigma_z/2}$ by
and angle $\theta=\pi$
\begin{align}
R_z(\pi)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
e^{i\pi/2} & 0 \\
0&e^{-i\pi/2}
\end{array}\right)
=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
i& 0 \\
0&-i
\end{array}\right)=i
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0&-1
\end{array}\right)
\end{align}
acting on $\vert LHP\rangle$ will yield $\vert RHP\rangle$ up to global inessential phase.

Basically the Jones vectors for the left- and right-handed polarization are eigenstates of $\sigma_y$ so lie opposite on the equator of the Poincaré sphere; a rotation about $R_z$ tracing a path along the equator should transform one into the other.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I knew some things but reading the paper confused me a lot and as a result it led me to question my knowledge on the matter.